# I need help deleting downloaded songs from iTunes using my iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to figure out how to delete these free songs I downloaded from iTunes using my iPhone? I downloaded them using my iPhone 4. So can I delete the same songs and how?

Answer (score 1):

In the Music app, find the song you want to delete in the list and swipe from left to right on the name of the song. Then tap the Delete button that appears.